# Touch navigation with Infinite Scroll and WP

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pagination, infinite-scroll

I'm using Infinite Scroll on a `WordPress` based site to load in more posts, and I just realized that the script won't run on `Touch based devices` (since it is initiated by scrolling). Are there any known, common workarounds for this?

Comment: @Estberg, Try Touch Punch: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/), Default jQuery Not allow the Touch Event

Comment: Great tip Venkat! Although I ended up using Lazy Load instead because of time limitations on the project, the Touch Punch seems to be what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

This might be solved replacing your Infite Scroll with LazyLoading.
Here is an example: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_container.html

It is also supposed to work for posts (not just images) so you can have the selector for your posts.

Optimized for mobile: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/improved-lazy-loading-mobile-devices-iphone-android-lazy-load-17

So you can set that it can load hundreds of posts, but when scrolling down, or sliding down on a mobile, it then will load more posts.

other popular sites using lazy loading or a form of this are: facebook, 9gag

Comment: Thanks, although I'd really prefer to stick with infinite scroll for this solution. Since it's already working for everything except touch devices I feel it would be a waste of time abandoning the current setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) it'll give **touch** class on the html element. Maybe you can use that to do something else on touch devices.

Comment: That could be a start, will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

> Use wordpress plugin for your post to display:

[Infinite-Scroll](http://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/)

> after installtion  set your setting  like this images:

[see the screenshort](http://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/screenshots/)

> set your no of post to display:
>
> setting -> reading

**Blog pages show at most: "no of post":**

> More details and demo to go..http://www.infinite-scroll.com/
>
> Want to see infinite scroll in action using this plugins?

http://aurgasm.us/